# Expanding command in \addchaptertocentry

Tags: expansion, datetime, scrbook

I'm using a counter to increment months in a journal and the `datetime` package to turn the counter into months. The months then become chapter titles in the document, so I have something like this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{month}

\newcommand{\newmonth}{%
  \addtocounter{month}{1}%
  \chapter{\monthname[\themonth]}
} 

\begin{document}

\newmonth

\lipsum

\newmonth

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

The month appears ok in the text, but not in the PDF index. I tracked down this problem to `\addchaptertocentry`, since I can reproduce it by calling `\addchaptertocentry{\monthname[\themonth]}`.

The `.aux` file contains the command verbatim:

```
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}\monthname [1]}{1}{chapter.1}}
```

How can I make it so that the `\monthname` command is expanded so that the PDF index looks right?

Edit:

My reason for using datetime here is to support multiple languages (French in this example), so I would rather avoid redefining the month list.

Comment: Note that the month names defined by `datetime` for French have lowercase initial.

Comment: @egreg: I did note that, and it's been another issue….

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need the optional argument which are making it non-expandable you could do

This version with language tests and french

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}



\newcounter{month}

\makeatletter

\def\@orgargctr=#1\relax\ifcase\@orgargctr{\ifcase#1 }
\expandafter\def\expandafter\monthname\expandafter{\csname\string\monthname\endcsname[\the\c@month]}

\expandafter\def\csname\string\monthname\endcsname[#1]{%
\if@dt@multilingual
\@ifundefined {monthname\languagename}%
{\csname \string\monthname english \endcsname [#1]}%
{\csname \string\monthname\languagename \endcsname [#1]}%
\else 
\csname\string\monthnameenglish\endcsname [#1]\fi}

%\expandafter\def\expandafter\monthnameenglish\expandafter{\csname\string\monthnameenglish\endcsname}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\newmonth}{%
  \addtocounter{month}{1}%
  \chapter{\monthname}
} 

\begin{document}



\newmonth

\lipsum

\newmonth


\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: My main reason for using `datetime` is to support multiple languages so I can create a generic `journal` class and rely on `babel`+`datetime` for month and dates translations. For this reason, redefining `\monthname` doesn't really help me.

Comment: It's possible to make an expandable test for optional arguments, eg bm package has one but there are always some restrictions, If you could make your MWE a bit less minimal and have a language switch or some such it should be possible to redefine it to cope. You _have_ to redefine \monthnaame or use something else as the definition you have doesn't work in expansion contexts

Comment: Just adding `\usepackage[french]{babel}` to the beginning of the preamble switches the month names to French.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: I added a french answer